# wordpress splitting the <li> to form 3 columns

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I currently use this to put my archived posts into a year then month listing with post count.  I am not sure how to break the `<li>` with count. I would like it to evenly break them into 3 columns with 4 `<li>` per column. I tried using CSS3 columns to do the trick but it would cause the `<li>`'s to be a bit wonky.

Here is my code:

```
     <?php
     $year_prev = null;
     $months = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month, 
                                  YEAR( post_date ) AS year, 
                                  COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts 
                                  WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) 
                                  and post_type = 'post' 
                                  GROUP BY month , year 
                                  ORDER BY post_date DESC");
     foreach($months as $month) :
     $year_current = $month->year;

     if ($year_current != $year_prev){
        if ($year_prev != null){?>
           </ul></div><div class="clear"></div>
         <?php } ?>
       <div class="archive-year-row"><h3><?php echo $month->year; ?></h3>
           <ul class="archive-list">
     <?php } ?>
                <li>
                   <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/<?php echo date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?>">
                       <span class="archive-month"><?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?></span>
                       <span class="archive-count"><?php echo $month->post_count; ?></span>
                   </a>
                </li>
       <?php $year_prev = $year_current;
       endforeach; ?>
       </ul>
```

Comment: Is the `div` what you're wanting to use as your column or the `ul`?

Comment: The `ul` is what i want to use not the `div` for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically just set $i = 1; right after opeing for each.
then iterate $i++; right before the closing foreach.

You can then use $i as a counter and test for the value of $i.

Something like this.

```
if($i == 4 || $i ==8){
  echo "</ul><ul>"; // this assumes you are opening and closing your column with the <ul></ul> tags
}
```

This is not completed code, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you ARWVISIONS! I will see what I can do.  I am pretty new to all this and still trying to figure out where and how to place things.

Comment: I have tried a few different ways ARWVISIONS and I seem to be lost.  This `<?php $i = 1; ?>` goes just before the first foreach statement or just before the `li`.  I put this `<?php $i++; ?>` just before the second endforeach statement. I used the if statement you gave in an if/else statement just after: `<ul class="archive-list">  <?php } ?>` What did I do wrong?

Comment: the $i = 1 set the initial value of your counter to 1. i++ increases the value of i by 1.  You need this so you can count the iterations. You place the initial $i=1; directly after the start of your foreach loop, and $i++ directly before the closing foreach.

Comment: This is the basic idea - 

    <ul>
      <li class="float-left"><!-- start of fist column-->
         <?php
          foreach($months as $month){
           $i=1;
           echo $month;
            if($i==4 || i==8){
            echo '</li><li class="float-left">'; // this will create a new column
             }
             i++;
           }

      </li><!-- end of last column -->
    </ul>

Comment: Oh dang now I see. Thank you so much for taking time to explain this to me so I can see it clearly.

Comment: can I get a check mark, so maybe one day I get enough rep to make a comment on this site, with out writing an answer first!?